# Data object with dependencies

Tags: c#, design-patterns, dependency-injection, unity-container

I tried to find an existing question but I'm not sure how to succinctly state it. Currently I have a collection of objects that each have a Status object. The status objects themselves hold three states. The original state read in from an external data source, the shown state and an output state. The original state is used for look up externally to state what the shown state should be. The shown state is the only state that can be updated by the user. The output state needs to change depending on if the program is in "visual mode" or "non-visual mode". I'd like to have this change when the shown state is updated. Before, the item state was not abstracted out and an item only had a single State. We then post processed the items and changed their state to the required output state. This takes 9+ seconds to go through all 120000 items and update their output state. I have now abstracted out the shown and output states due to previous refactoring and would like to additionally optimize this output state conversion. I of course thought of doing the output conversion right before the data is written out however there are multiple files the data is written to and thus would need to do this conversion in multiple places.

Example: Shown state is being updated to "Bad", Thus if the program is in "Visual mode", the output state needs to update to "Good". But if the program is in "not-visual mode" then it gets set to "Bad".

So my question is how do I manage logic dependencies needed for the data objects inside a collection? I thought of using dependency injection however I'd probably have to do it manually instead of through the "magic"of Unity. Plus it seems messy when it would be nice to construct a new Status object by giving it only the starting State. The collection is inside a master object so I did think of having methods there to manage the collection but that seems a bit to strict and harder to just iterate over and read/update the Status objects.

Here is a representation of the class structures:

```
class MyMapObject
{
    // This will have 100000+ items
    public Dictionary<Coordinate,Item> MapCollection { get; set; }
    /*
        Various other properties and methods
        ...
    */
}

class Item
{
    public ItemStatus Status { get; set;}
    /*
        Various other properties and methods
        ...
    */
}

class ItemStatus
{
    public State OriginalState { get; private set; }

    public State OutputState { get; private set; }

    public State ShownState 
    {
        get { return _shownState; }
        set
        {
            _shownState = value;
            SetOutputState();
        }
    }

    private void SetOutputState()
    {
        case DieState.Bad:   // How do I inject visualInspectionMode?
            OutputState = visualInspectionMode ? DieState.Good : DieState.Bad;
            break;
        // other states ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show some code? I understand the status but I don't understand you want to attach the status to and how much info you want persisted.

Comment: I've added the class structure to help. The MyMapObject will be the object that gets passed around the program during execution.

Answer (score 1):

> The status objects themselves hold three states. The original state read in from an external data source, the current state and an output state.

We're going to think about the State Pattern and so this is troubling. You'll have state objects, not mere `enum` properties. The [Memento Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/memento-pattern.html) pattern allows reverting to a previous state, but at the very least we're looking at some kind of linked list structure.

`CurrentState` vs `OutPutState` sounds like you're defining the same state twice. My initial *guess* is that we want to build a state object of `CurrentState` that will *behave* in a "output state" manner. I.E. `OutputState` should be a method.

> The collection is inside a master object so I did think of having methods there to manage the collection but that seems a bit to strict and harder to just iterate over and read/update the Status objects.

This is actually good if you really want to control the collection. This can make your object look, feel, and behave like a `MasterObject` rather than a generic .net collection object.

---

> I thought of using dependency injection however I'd probably have to do it manually instead of through the "magic"of Unity.

Use the `Unity` container every time an object changes state? Sounds like ultra-overkill. And a misuse of the DI container concept as I understand it from [*Dependency Injection in .NET*](http://www.manning.com/seemann/)

---

> Plus it seems messy when it would be nice to construct a new Status object by giving it the starting State.

BINGO!

> The collection is inside a master object so I did think of ...

Design your state machine first, then worry about a collection.

**Clearly Define States**

Is it `Bad` or is it `NotVisualMode`?  Is it `Good` or `VisualMode`? First, "good" and "bad" don't mean anything. Second you defining then re-defining the states. Ditto for `CurrentState` and `OutputState` it would seem.

**Clearly Define Action -> State Transitions**

1. So *Application becomes visual* causes a change to `Visual` state.

**State Pattern, Generally**

1. Define an `interface`, declaring a method for each "action" that causes state change
2. Write a concrete class for each state and implement the interface.
3. When *something* happens we change state we create a new state object. The object's methods behave according to the state it is. This is when so-called `OutputState` can do its thing.

"Actions" cause state change. The application going from "visual" to "non-visual" to whatever can be thought of as the same thing.

---

> Currently I have a collection of objects that each have a Status object. The status objects themselves hold three states.

I suspect this should be a single class. A state object is not just a bunch of `bool` or `enum`s, it is also behavior appropriate for the given state.

**Said another way, you may want a `enum` property that says I'm in a `StateOf.Confusion` but it the totality of the fields, properties, and polymorphic methods in that object that IS that state.**

---

**A Thought about SOLID**

**I** - Interface Segregation.  I said the state pattern `interface` will declare the methods that determine the next state. I did not include the `OutputState` method.

`OutputState` and any other "state-polymorphic" methods should be declared in a separate `interface` or templated `abstract` class. If there is common processing structure then an `abstract` class will be the way to go. [See my answer to this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/251130/domain-specific-interfaces/251495#251495).

Comment: I updated my question to try and add some clarity. I feel that your answer doesn't quite address my question as it appears you are in an unfortunate StateOf.Confusion.

Comment: Paraphrasing Cypher, "StateOf.Confusion is bliss", so... Do all `MapCollection Items` have the same state? If so then have a single `ItemStatus` that every `Item` references.  [`Application.Properties`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.properties%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) may be a way to globally communicate visualness.

Comment: No, each item has it's own ItemStatus object which hold their own states (original, shown, output).